# Android : Retrieving data from text field in pop up is throwing errors

Tags: android

I am trying to get text field value from a pop up on clicking Save button. But it is throwing errors.

Code :-

```
final Button btn_ContactDetails = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_ContactDetails);
btn_ContactDetails.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactdetails, null, true);

        final PopupWindow popUp = new PopupWindow(layout, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        popUp.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        popUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popUp.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                    popUp.dismiss();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Button btnDismiss = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
            btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    popUp.dismiss();
                }
            });

        //On click Save - Contact Details
        Button btn_Save_ContactDetails = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_Save_ContactDetails);
        btn_Save_ContactDetails.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                EditText mEdit, sEdit;
                mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_HouseNameNumber);
                sEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_Address1);
                sEdit.setText(mEdit.getText().toString());//THIS LINE IS THROWING ERROR
                popUp.dismiss();
            }
        });
        popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
});
```

Error :-

```
06-12 03:21:37.828: E/AndroidRuntime(518): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 03:21:37.828: E/AndroidRuntime(518): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 03:21:37.828: E/AndroidRuntime(518):  at sai.om.SaiActivity$3$3.onClick(SaiActivity.java:171)
06-12 03:21:37.828: E/AndroidRuntime(518):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-12 03:21:37.828: E/AndroidRuntime(518):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-12 03:21:37.828: E/AndroidRuntime(518):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-12 03:21:37.828: E/AndroidRuntime(518):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-12 03:21:37.828: E/AndroidRuntime(518):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-12 03:21:37.828: E/AndroidRuntime(518):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-12 03:21:37.828: E/AndroidRuntime(518):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 03:21:37.828: E/AndroidRuntime(518):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-12 03:21:37.828: E/AndroidRuntime(518):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-12 03:21:37.828: E/AndroidRuntime(518):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-12 03:21:37.828: E/AndroidRuntime(518):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help me find what I am doing wrong here?
I have provided comments to the line throwing error.

Comment: so your problem is `java.lang.NullPointerException` in your `onClick` method

Comment: But where am I wrong? What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sEdit.setText( mEdit.getText());//THIS LINE IS THROWING ERROR
```

The most likely reason is that either `sEdit` or `mEdit` is `null` (or both).

Double check your layout file to make sure you have `EditTexts` with ids of `txt_HouseNameNumber` and `txt_Address1`. In other words, make sure they're spelt correctly and remember case-sensitivity.

**EDIT:** Perhaps you should be using `layout.findViewById(...)` as follows?...

```
mEdit = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_HouseNameNumber);
sEdit = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_Address1);
```

Comment: yes I have tried mEdit.getText().toString(), but it doesn't even change the error. And the ids are absolutely right, I have copied the ids from xml.

Comment: @Squonk : Haha we both got there within a second of each other :)

Comment: @HXCaine : lol - yeah. I saw your comment appear just as I posted mine. :D

Comment: @HXCaine Squonk : yes yes yes...Thanks for all the help. Really. I changed code as you said i.e., mEdit = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_HouseNameNumber);
sEdit = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_Address1);
& changed modifier of layout to "final" and it worked. yes Thanks both of you...Now I can go to sleep

Comment: Good to hear. Eclipse should have been warning you about the 'final' keyword, as well as the invalidity of using getText() without toString(). Are you using Eclipse or compiling on the command line?

Comment: @HXCaine Yes I am using Eclipse. It warned me about "final" but it did not warn me about the invalidity of using getText() without toString(). And actually just a second before posting this question, I tried removing toString() and then copied the code. So it was my fault actually. :D

Answer (score 1):

You are using `findViewById()` within the activity, whereas you should be retrieving it from the parent view.

Try obtaining the views from v:

```
mEdit = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_HouseNameNumber);
sEdit = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_Address1);
```

Alternatively, try using `layout.findViewById()` or `arg0.findViewById()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you clipped some of the error message off when copying.  Also, it should be

```
sEdit.setText( mEdit.getText().toString() );
```

The method setText() is expecting an Editable object passed through, so by calling .toString() it changes to the correct type.  I don't think that matches up with the NullPointerException though.  For that, either sEdit or mEdit might not be  getting initialized properly which means you are either trying to do null.setText or sEdit.setText(null).  Again, try posting the error message again because I couldn't differentiate which of those cases it could be.  Or add some simple if statements to check which one isn't being set properly.

Comment: Yes you are right. What I have concluded is that error is because of sEdit.setText(null). But I am filling up the text field before clicking the Save button.

Comment: I think you can help out here. I have copied the errors correctly. I am not sure but it might be related to pop up because textfields are in pup up